# What can I do to avoid a css file interfering with a piece of code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this piece of code:

```
 <div class="icons-container" id="fragment-13">
        <div class="icon-up">
            <img src="assets/images/PricingIconUp.png" alt="">
        </div>

        <!-- Piece of code where css doesn't have interfere -->
        <p class="fragments-title">Simple, straight <br> forward pricing</p>
        <p class="fragments-paragraph">$6.95 online stock and ETF trades. <br> No trade or balance minimuns. You <br> may also qualify for $0 trades.<sup>2</sup> <br> Other fees may apply<sup>3</sup></p>
        <!-- Piece of code where css doesn't have interfere -->
    </div>
```

I am using Sass btw. And it is actually a very big piece of html where I don't a jquery-ui css file to interfere.

What should I do?

Comment: which element is getting interfered with which rule in jquery ui?

Comment: @karthick are some elements of the jquery-uii-tabs plugin. I have those tabs nested so the parent is affecting its children.

Comment: The simplest way not to apply code to a part of your page is to render it as an `<iframe>` (it's a new document, you load what you want in it). But this will add a whole new level of complexity to responsiveness. Depending on case and content, it's doable, but not sure if it's not better to just rename the classes in both CSS and HTML for that particular portion. Refactoring is easy with the right tool (a proper IDE).